# how to take random words after a sentence in random index

Tags: python, regex, string, cpu-word

here's the String variable

```
question = "i need to know about something..."
```

how do i get the words after "i need to know about", if sometimes the question variable changes become something like this:

```
question = " i need to know about something..."
```

or

```
question = "hmmm.... i need to know about something"
```

i mean, no matter where index is, but i need to know what the random word come after this sentence -> "i need to know about", in this case the result will be "something..."

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty solution would be to use `str.strip()`. It's quick and dirty because it's case insensitive and will only work if the exact string is present

```
In [22]: "i need to know about something...".split("i need to know about")
Out[22]: ['', ' something...']

In [23]: "hmmm.... i need to know about something".split("i need to know about")
Out[23]: ['hmmm.... ', ' something']

In [24]: "hmmm.... i need to know about  something".split("i need to know about")
Out[24]: ['hmmm.... ', '  something']

In [25]: "hmmm.... i need to know  about something".split("i need to know about")
Out[25]: ['hmmm.... i need to know  about something']
```

The last case won't work as the strings don't match exactly (note the 2 spaces between `know` and `about`.

A regular expression as some of the other answers suggest will be much more comprehensive

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
question = "hmmm.... i need to know about something"

new_data = question[question.index("i need to know about")+len("i need to know about"):]
```

Output:

```
something
```

Using regex:

```
import re

data = re.findall("(?<=i need to know about)\s[a-zA-Z\s]+", question)

print(data)
```

Output:

```
[' something']
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a string then you could just get the index of the string you're looking for and get everything after that, like so:

```
start = question.index('i need to know about')
finish = start + len('i need to know about')
print(question[finish:]) # something...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Regular expressions.

```
import re
s = "hmmm.... i need to know about something"
regexp = re.compile("i need to know about(.*)$")
print(regexp.search(s).group(1))
```

Outputs:

```
 something
```

If you want to clean the output, you can always `.strip()`

```
print(regexp.search(s).group(1).strip())
```

Outputs:

```
something
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to extract the content after "i need to know about".

```
import re

pattern = ".*?i need to know about (.*)"

content = re.search(pattern, sentence).group(1)
```